# How to send an email in bcc using Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Let us say I want to send an email to `recipient@xyz.com` with bcc copy sent to `bcc@xyz.com`.

When `bcc@xyz.com` is receiving an email he should see `recipient@xyz.com` in the To field, and `bcc@xyz.com` in the bcc field.

But when `bcc@xyz.com` receives the email, he is not able to see `recipient@xyz.com` in the To field.

I tried to create and send email using mail composer instead of transports but it is not working as expected.

I also tried cc but cc is not working as expected.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    auth: {
        user: testAccount.user,
        pass: testAccount.pass
    },
    tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
});

const mailData = {
    from: 'xyz@xyz.com',
    to: 'recipient@xyz.com',
    bcc: 'bcc@xyz.com',
    subject: 'Sample Mail',
    html: text
}

const result = await transporter.sendMail(mailData);

console.log('Mail Sent! \t ID: ' + result.messageId);
```

When the email is received, I expect **bcc@xyz.com** to see **recipient@xyz.com** in the To: field.

Comment: Can't get this question, because I'm having this behaviour by default when sending e-mail, without the need to do anything with `envelope`.

Answer (score 21):

See [envelope](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/envelope/)

> SMTP envelope is usually auto generated from from, to, cc and bcc fields in the message object but if for some reason you want to specify it yourself (custom envelopes are usually used for VERP addresses), you can do it with the envelope property in the message object.

```
let message = {
  ...,
  from: 'mailer@nodemailer.com', // listed in rfc822 message header
  to: 'daemon@nodemailer.com', // listed in rfc822 message header
  envelope: {
    from: 'Daemon <deamon@nodemailer.com>', // used as MAIL FROM: address for SMTP
    to: 'mailer@nodemailer.com, Mailer <mailer2@nodemailer.com>' // used as RCPT TO: address for SMTP
  }
}
```

In your case following mailData should do the work:

```
const mailData = {
    from: 'xyz@xyz.com',
    to: 'recipient@xyz.com',
    bcc: 'bcc@xyz.com',
    subject: 'Sample Mail',
    html: text,
    envelope: {
        from: 'xyz@xyz.com',
        to: 'recipient@xyz.com'
    }
}
```